# Executable code from object (preferably without eval())

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this code to execute in a backbone project:

```
main.key1 = new view.a.b.c({prop: val});
main.key2 = new view.x.y.z({prop: val});
//and so on, about 10 views with about 5 identical properties
```

I have an object like this defined inside a main object:

```
var main = this;    
var viewmap = {key1: 'view.a.b.c', key2: 'view.x.y.z'} // and so on
```

What I want is to use my object to replace the code above, because the views have to come from a map.

I'm not 100% against `eval()`, but I'd prefer not to have to use it. However, if that is the only way, I'll take it. Problem is, I'm not even sure how to use `eval()` for this purpose.

I tried something like:

```
for(view in viewmap){
    main[view] = eval('new ' + viewmap[view] + '({prop: val});');
}
```

But it's not working.

Please help.

Comment: A way without eval would be to split the string by `.` and loop through gradually advancing through the view object `viewObj = viewObj[arr[i]]`

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the string at `.`s then looping over the resulting array and using bracket notation to find the next object, you'd end up with code that looks something like this

```
function getObj(base, path) {
    var arr = path.split('.'), // ["view", "a", "b", "c"]
        i;
    for (i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) // start from 1 to ignore "view"
        if (!(base = base[arr[i]]))
            break; // error handling?
    return base;
}
// now your loop that uses `new` on the result of the invocation of the function
var viewPath;
for(viewPath in viewmap){
    main[viewPath] = new (getObj(view, viewmap[viewPath]))({prop: val});
}
```

Notice the extra pair of parenthesis around the `getObj` call so the interpreter doesn't confuse this with the `new`

Comment: @Tushar if it's not assigning to the correct place it's because I didn't update the assign on main properly, and messed up `path` vs `arr` D: fixed in edit